# Problem with displaying the icon on the Xamarin start screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

In all mipmap folders, except mipmap-anydpi-v26, I replaced the application icon from the default one with my own, it is displayed correctly on the emulator, and on the real device that I use for debugging, there is just a white screen. It may be necessary to edit the mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder, but I do not know how to do this, since it is located there.xml files

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem please see:
See https://github.com/gmck/XamarinBasicSplashScreen

Answer (score 0):

> It may be necessary to edit the mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder, but I do not know how to do this, since it is located there.xml files

About this, you can refer to James Montemagno's Tutorial video: [Beautiful iOS & Android Adaptive Icons Generated in Minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEAyAf3_MpU). It introduces in detail how to change app icon.

Hope it can help you!